# OpenSSL equivalent for Java/BouncyCastle signature

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle

I have a piece of software doing a digital signature as follows.

```
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1", "BC");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/NoPadding", "BC");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    byte[] hash = md.digest("message".getBytes());
    byte[] signature = cipher.doFinal(hash);
```

I want to replace it by some lines of batch/openssl, but failed reproducing this signature. Basically it's a combination of a SHA1 and RSA, which isn't that bad. I was wondering why hash and encryption are separated. Both ways doing this with openssl resulting in a different signature (ignoring the format):

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -binary msg.txt > hash
openssl rsautl -sign -inkey priv.pem -in hash -hexdump
```

and

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign priv.pem -hex < msg.txt
```

So there's something I am missing...

UPDATE:

Thanks for your comments! Of course this Java code is NOT the way to do signatures properly, but the code that verifies is not in my hand, and my goal is to create a signature that could be verified. I will make suggestions to change the whole thing, though.

But I've finally managed to reproduce the signature. I do not answer the question myself, because I want an proper openssl solution. So here is what I got:

The Java code above **does padding**! The hash code is prepadded with zero bytes to a length of 256!

Comment: I tried also `openssl pkeyutl -sign -in hash -inkey priv.pem -pkeyopt digest:sha1 -hexdump`, which gives the same output as the second call above (`openssl dgst...`), but still not match the java output.

Comment: Also see [RSA encryption with private key and decryption with a public key](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2123) on Information Security SE.

Comment: @jww [This one: "Is RSA encryption of a cryptographic hash with a private key the same as signature generation?"](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/1172) is even more on-topic. As indicated we don't disagree on this fact. RSA encryption should not be used for signature generation and RSA encryption should not be performed using the private key.

Comment: The above UPDATE is wrong to a certain degree. RSA is performed on integers; you can put as many zero bytes in front of a big endian integer as you want, but that does not really pad the *input to RSA* as that's just a number. Similar to 1 and 01 being identical values. For calculations that are secure against side channel attacks you may want to use statically sized integers though.

Comment: **WARNING**: above code is specific to a problem of avh. RSA should not be used without the correct padding, or with the broken SHA-1 hash function, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found so far is doing a manual padding with 236 zero bytes (padding) and another temporary file (hash).

```
COPY padding hash
openssl dgst -sha1 -binary msg.txt >>hash
openssl pkeyutl -sign -in hash -inkey priv.pem -out signature -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:none
```

I tried to use `openssl dgst` instead and specifying various padding schemes, but wasn't successful. I assume that openssl does not support this padding scheme, and doubt that it's a standard one.

Answer (score 3):

The Java code performs raw or textbook RSA over a SHA-1 hash. This is not secure, you should use either PKCS#1 v1.5 padding (for signature generation) or PSS in your Java code. PKCS#1 v1.5 for instance is performed using the `"SHA1withRSA"` algorithm string for the `Signature` class.

Although it's not secure I tried to replicate the result of the Java code using the `-raw` argument, but this failed because of a check within the OpenSSL code:

```
$ openssl rsautl -encrypt -raw -inkey priv.pem -in hash -hexdump
RSA operation error
3077884104:error:0406B07A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_none:data too small for key size:rsa_none.c:76:
```

so OpenSSL doesn't let you make this mistake. I tried signing as well by the way, same result.

By default OpenSSL uses PKCS#1 v1.5 padding (for signing) for signature generation and PKCS#1 v1.5 padding (for encryption) for encryption. That will generate different output than the raw signatures in the Java code.

Comment: By the by: this is a pointer to a list not yet completed: [why RSA raw is insecure](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20085/1172)

Comment: +1 it's the padding. Some small additions: due to dried grapes, `rsautl -sign [-pkcs]` does NOT do steps 1&2 of EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5, which are the hash AND the make-SEQ-AlgId-hashval (which adds a nearly fixed prefix); it only does pad-01-many-FF-00 and modexp-private. `pkeyutl -sign` for RSA with padding=pkcs1 includes the make-SEQ step *if* you specify digest:whatever, which the OP did. (`dgst -sign` does all steps, starting with hash.) `pkeyutl` also supports PSS, which `rsautl` doesn't, nor Java with the usual Sun/Oracle providers, but BouncyCastle does, and which of course is randomized.

Comment: Thanks for providing the additional info, Dave! By the way "due to dried grapes"? Does that refer to some raisin d'etre?

Comment: *"The Java code performs raw or textbook RSA over a SHA-1 hash"* - The Java code is wrong. "encrypt with the private key" is not a valid cryptographic operation. Period.

Comment: @jww I agree with that, but your answer/comments do not explain the result and neither supplies an answer to the question. Note that encryption with the private key is often used in cryptographic libraries to implement "special" signatures, such as the one for SSL.

Comment: @Maarten - the stuff under your answer has nothing to do with the stuff under my answer.

Comment: @jww Right. So you are downvoting because padding differences are not to blaim? And you are doing that long after I've posted by answer and comments? Seems rather far fetched to me.

Comment: @Maarten - perhaps you should check out Sun's [RSASignature class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/security/rsa/RSASignature.java) and the [crtCrypt method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/security/rsa/RSACore.java#RSACore.crtCrypt%28byte%5B%5D%2Cjava.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey%29). They perform the modular exponentiation using `BigIntegers`, and they don't try to "encrypt with the private key".

Comment: No need to post the same comment twice just to prove a point.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that contents of your msg.txt is different from `"message"` that you are hashing in Java source. I tried your sample on linux and got this:

```
# echo message > msg.txt
# xxd msg.txt
0000000: 6d65 7373 6167 650a                      message.
```

You will notice additional line feed (0x0a) at the end of the string.

Once you trim that:

```
# dd if=msg.txt of=msg2.txt bs=1 count=7
# xxd msg2.txt
0000000: 6d65 7373 6167 65                        message
```

you get the same checksum as the Java code produces.

As far as the RSA is concerned, once you get the same source data, there is no reason that shouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of couse I already double-checked the messages, they're the same and have no trailing line feed. The hash generated by the java code is also the same hash generated by openssl. There must be another reason....

Comment: This could have explained the differences, but this seems guesswork. Instead ask the user to try this in a comment first. Generally people won't post the same thing as answer if you do that (well, at least for the cryptography oriented questions that are not very easily answered).

Answer (score 0):

> cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

I'm fairly certain this is not quite correct.

There's no such operation as "encrypt with the private key". At a high level, when you create a signature, you treat the hash and padding to be signed as an instance of cipher text. You then "decrypt with the private key" to arrive at the signature.

If you really want to "encrypt with the private key", then you should investigate a Signature Scheme with Recovery. That's probably the closest you are going to get to "encrypt with the private key".

You should probably be using one of Java's built in signature schemes, especially if you are trying to interop with OpenSSL command line utilities. See, for example, [Java Tutorial » Security » RSA algorithm](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/RSASignatureGeneration.htm).

Otherwise, take a look at Sun sources for `RSASignature`. They work with `BigIntegers` directly and perform the exponentiation, and *don't* try to do "encrypt with private key". See, for example, Sun's [RSASignature class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/security/rsa/RSASignature.java) and the [crtCrypt method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/security/rsa/RSACore.java#RSACore.crtCrypt%28byte%5B%5D%2Cjava.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey%29).

Comment: Oops, I voted this up but the explanation is wrong and it doesn't explain the problem. Signature generation consists of hashing, padding and then modular exponentiation. Now the padding is required for secure operation, and should be PKCS#1 v1.5 *for signing* or PSS. The modular exponentiation is always the same operation (using either the private exponent / CRT or the public exponent) but even in the PKCS#1 standard they have assigned it a different name for signing/encryption *because those two are different operations*.

Comment: @Maarten - I was only providing an answer to what was wrong with what he was doing. He can look elsewhere if he needs signatures or the CRT explained.

Comment: That's not my point. The point is that even though the code in the question is not correct, your answer doesn't explain why the method would be returning the wrong response. There is no difference in encrypting or decrypting with a private key if padding is not used.

Comment: @Maarten - I was not trying to explain how to do it. I'm not sure where you are getting that from my answer. The theory and techniques are above him, and he should not be doing it. He should use something Java offers for signatures.

Comment: We agree that nobody should be doing this. But this doesn't seem to be his own code, and your answer does not answer the question. The operation has taken place in Java, whether you like it or not. Saying that there "is no such operation" while it has just taken place doesn't solve anything.

Comment: @Maarten - I told him what he was doing wrong. That's my answer. If you can make that Java code work with `openssl rsautl -sign ...`, then I suggest you provide the updated code for him.

Comment: So, you "decrypt with a private key" to derive the signature. Do you mean the modular exponentiation + *unpadding* or just modular exponentiation? In the former, signing is not the same as decryption with the private key. In the latter, encryption is identical to decryption when applied to the same key.

Comment: @Maarten - perhaps you should check out Sun's [RSASignature class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/security/rsa/RSASignature.java) and the [crtCrypt method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/security/rsa/RSACore.java#RSACore.crtCrypt%28byte%5B%5D%2Cjava.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey%29). They perform the modular exponentiation using `BigIntegers`, and they don't try to "encrypt with the private key".

Comment: Not disagreeing with that. Code is code. Removed downvote, at least you're supplying a solution now. Still doesn't explain the difference in the result, but OK.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments, which helped me a little more to understand this. But Maarten is right: the part of the code that verifies the signature is not in my hand, so I have not the possibility to fix that.